# Baby Rudin Exercise 10.8, Showing Compact Support

Tags: real-analysis, integration

[Here is Baby Rudin exercise 10.8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5YO7.jpg):

> 8. Let $H$ be the parallelogram in $R^{2}$ whose vertices are $(1,1),(3,2),(4,5),(2,4)$. Find the affine map $T$ which sends $(0,0)$ to $(1,1),(1,0)$ to $(3,2),(0,1)$ to $(2,4)$. Show that $J_{x}=5$. Use $T$ to convert the integral
>    $$
>    \alpha=\int_{H} e^{x-y} d x d y
>    $$
>    to an integral over $I^{2}$ and thus compute $\alpha$.

So I think we need to use the change of variable theorem 10.9. But that theorem requires that f has compact support st supp(f) $\subset$ T(D). However, here f = $e^{(x-y)}$.

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the concept of support, but f is never 0 so I believe the support is simply all of $R^2$. But this isn't compact, so I don't see how we can satisfy this condition. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You are only integrating on H, which is equivalent to integrating the function which equals f on H and is 0 everywhere else. This function is supported on H, which is compact.

Comment: @Aaron Ooh great point, thanks!

Comment: @Aaron Sorry I'm still confused though. Because we're actually ultimately going to compute the integral on some D and transform to H. Here, D isn't in H. So if we make f 0 everywhere but H, then it will be 0 on D, so it seems that transform definitely shouldn't work?

Comment: No, the ultimate goal is to compute the integral on H, which you do by using change of variables and computing a different integral on the unit square which will have the same value.

Comment: @Aaron Yeah, but if we change f to equal 0 on the unit square, then that integral is just going to be 0 right?

Comment: We aren’t changing f, we are viewing it as being zero outside of H. And when we do change of variables, we are integrating a different function which is zero outside of the unit square.

Comment: @Aaron Ok thanks, I understand what we're doing. I don't see why you're allowed to do that though? I mean the theorem 10.9 just references f and uses it as the same function in both integrals, it doesn't say we can change it like this.

Answer (score 0):

You need the integrand to be compactly supported if you are integrating on the whole space.

Comment: Thanks! Hmm, trying to understand...So you're saying if I'm only integrating on a subset it just has to be compactly supported on that subset? Yeah that makes sense looking at the theorem

Comment: No. I am saying if the integrand is continuous and you are integrating on a compact set then there is no need to look at the support. If the integrand is continuous and you are integrating on an unbounded set, then you need something more..

Comment: Oh I see, thanks for clarifying. We haven't covered the proof of the variables theorem yet, maybe when we do it'll become obvious that integrating on a compact set gives what we need.

Comment: @lightnesscaster The support of a function is the closure of the set of inputs that have  non-zero values.  So if you are integrating over a compact set,  you can treat all the values outside that set as 0 and get compact support automatically.  Note if you are doing real integration, all you need is the function be integrated over a bounded region,  because the support is the closure of that region, and closed+bounded=compact in the Reals

Comment: @Alan Awesome, that makes sense, thank you!

Comment: @Alan Hmm sorry actually now I'm confused again. We also need that supp(f) $\subset$ T(D), where T is the change of variable transformation and T: D $-> R^k$. So since supp(f) $\subset$ T(D), then I guess we need to make supp(f) = T(D) for all non-zero values in T(D)? But then we're setting f to be 0 on D. And if we set f to be 0 on D then we're no longer transforming from f on D but from 0 on D, and it seems like the transformation doesn't work? And if we let the support not be 0 on D, then it doesn't lie on T(D) since D isn't in T(D) here.